# Express server receiving get requests for old bundles

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, create-react-app

I used create-react-app. I since have ejected. I have webpack configured to split each page's scripts into bundles. I was using a hash in the name, but changed it to a plain name. My html file's script src are all set correctly to point to my new bundles. When i sendFile() the html it starts making get requests to all the bundles. This works until I send a get from an email verification link, res.sendFile the html to the browser, and it opens a new tab, but it makes its gets for the bundles to old hashed bundle names. The src in the html is not pointing to where it is making the requests to. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Pretty sure it made no difference, but I uninstalled webpack-chunk-hash. What I think the real problem was is that I had a cache worker thing messing with the browser, deleted that and started to get perfectly predictable requests from the browser. Website now works great, workflow completed.